# What does an "L" shape mean beside a note in the lower staff?

Tags: piano, notation, sheet-music

Sorry if this is trivial but I am self taught and cannot find the meaning of this bracket on a sheet.

[image]

This is taken from Merry Christmas Mr Lawrence by Ryuichi Sakamoto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My only supposition is that the writer is suggesting that the C being pointed to can be played using the right hand.

Comment: HA, I've just thought - maybe - the first flat - Bb - is missed off the example.........So both staves are treble clef.   Give us a bit more music to explore please !

Comment: Even so the left hand stretch from Bb to C isn't too comfortable.

Comment: The left hand stretch is no comfortable. Which is why the bracket is :) (time sig: 12/8).

Answer (score 15):

The bracket means that the high C on the low staff is meant to be played with the right hand.

Left hand: Bb-F-Ab

Right hand: C-Eb (and the rest of the melody).

Answer (score 0):

*Looks more like a bracket than an "L" to me.*  I would venture it to mean that the 8va (the upward jump in register) extends to those notes also of the left hand (the bass clef).  Anyone concur?

Comment: No, the accepted answer is correct unless the notes were written by someone who likes to confuse people with nonstandard meanings of standard notation.